# Ruby : get more then one decimal zero?

Tags: ruby-2.0, cubes

My code:

```
def cube_root(x)
  a = x**(1/3.0)
  p = a.ceil
  puts p
end
gets.chomp.to_i.times do 
    q = gets.chomp.to_i
    cube_root(q)
end
```

`input`
2
8
1000

`output`
2.0
10.0

**Expected output**
2.0000000000
10.0000000000

Comment: I'm sure you're able to indent your code better than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to print extra decimal places you can try:

```
puts "%.8f" %p
```

or

```
sprintf "%.8f" %p
```

where 8 means eight decimal places.

Comment: if input is 2 then output must be 1.2599210498

Comment: In your code you are calling "ceil" which is going to return an integer, if you want to get n decimal places you should use "round"